# Is there a way to declare a variable sized vector globally from a function?

Tags: c++, vector, global-variables

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int grid(int x, int y)
{
    static vector<vector<int>> vec(x + 1, vector<int>(y + 1, 0));
    if (vec[x][y] != 0)
        return vec[x][y];
    if (x == 0 || y == 0)
        return 0;
    if (x == 1 && y == 1)
        return 1;
    vec[x][y] = grid(x - 1, y) + grid(x, y - 1);
    return vec[x][y];
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << grid(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

I initialised a 2D vector "**vec**" inside the *grid* function with the vector size as argument. If I needed "**vec**" in some other function how would I use it without passing it as a parameter?

I am unable to initialise the vector globally since it has variable size.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid passing the vector to functions?  global state is highly frowned upon as it makes the code harder to reason about.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This sounds like an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm not asking what your whole (possibly 200+ line) project is supposed to be doing. I'm asking what you're trying to do in this piece of code that requires an `std::vector` to be globally accessible but declared in the scope of a function.

Comment: @scohe001 I just wanted to know if by any means we can create a dynamic global vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously can't create a global vector when the size of the vector depends on user input. But you can resize an existing vector.

```
vector<vector<int>> vec; // create at zero size

int grid(int x, int y)
{
    vec.resize(x + 1, vector<int>(y + 1, 0)); // resize to required size
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are developing in c++ not c. You can use class to achieve this.

It would look like:

```cpp
using namespace std;
class grid
{
public:
   grid(int x, int y)
   {
       mGrid = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(x + 1, vector<int>(y + 1, 0));
   }

   int getValue(int x, int y)
   {
       return vec[x][y];
   }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mGrid;
};


int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    grid myGrid(x, y);
    cout << myGrid.getValue(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

And every method you create inside class will have access to this member named mGrid.

Otherwise if you can't use class you can create global vector and change it during grid method like that:

```cpp
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> vec;

int grid(int x, int y)
{
    vec(x + 1, vector<int>(y + 1, 0));
    if (vec[x][y] != 0)
        return vec[x][y];
    if (x == 0 || y == 0)
        return 0;
    if (x == 1 && y == 1)
        return 1;
    vec.resize(x + 1, vector<int>(y + 1, 0));
    return vec[x][y];
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << grid(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to add error handling or exceptions to avoid core dump :)

Comment: There's `.resize` missing from your second example.